# Javascript - Uploading CSV to S3 by presigned URL - file contains boundary data

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am uploading a CSV file to S3 using a presigned URL, but when I open the file in S3 I notice that the data is wrapped in the multipart formdata / boundary information.  How do I get only the raw data to be in the file?

I have -

Generating the presigned URL

```
   return s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: 'temp.csv',
        Expires: 30,
    });
```

In postman
- I have it set to a PUT request
- I have no extra headers
- I have the file added to the body of the request using the postman UI

Request Body -

[image: Request Body]

Request Headers -

[image: Request Headers]

Contents of the CSV look like -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Got this working - looks to be because of Postman setting the `Content-Type` to multipart/form-data.  I changed the request body to be of type `binary` and uploaded the file to the postman UI that way.  I manually set the `Content-Type` to `text/csv`